# Why it retrun me only the value of the json and not the key?

Tags: python, json

I want to check if the reaction (in discord) that was added is in the right channel and on the right message.
I stored the channel id and message id in a .json file
But python does not want to send the value of the key and i don't know how to solve this problem

`{"931966019612864623": "931966020808228922"}` <== this is my json file

`931966020808228922` <== this is what python return

Here is my code

```py
        elif payload.emoji.name == '':
            
            if payload.user_id != self.client.user.id:
                count = 0
                with open(ticket_msg, 'r') as f:
                    distros_dict = json.load(f)
                    await channell.send(distros_dict)

                for key in distros_dict.keys():
                    channel_id = distros_dict.get(key)
                    await channell.send(str(channell.id) + ' ' + str(channel_id))

                    if int(channell.id) == int(channel_id):
                        count+=1

                if count > 0:

                    await channell.send("ok")
                else:
                    return
```

I've tested to replace `for key in distros_dict.keys()` by `for key in distros_dict.items()` , but it return me this error:

```py
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\baron_btjit4i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\baron_btjit4i\Desktop\Autrebot\Cogs\ticket.py", line 170, in on_raw_reaction_add
    if int(channell.id) == int(channel_id):
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: `for key, value in distros_dict.items():`

Comment: it don't work, it return me 931966020808228922

Comment: It does work and return you pair of key an value.

Comment: the key is 931966020808228922 and the value is None

Comment: It returns you content of your dictionary.

Comment: Okay, but how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
for key, value in distros_dict.items()
```

which i updated

```
        elif payload.emoji.name == '':
           
           if payload.user_id != self.client.user.id:
               count = 0
               with open(ticket_msg, 'r') as f:
                   distros_dict = json.load(f)
                   await channell.send(distros_dict)

               for key, value in distros_dict.items():
                   channel_id = key
                   await channell.send(str(channell.id) + ' ' + str(channel_id))

                   if int(channell.id) == int(channel_id):
                       count+=1

               if count > 0:

                   await channell.send("ok")
               else:
                   return
```

Comment: it dosen't work, it return 931966020808228922 ;-;

Comment: replace `channel_id = distros_dict.get(key) ` with `channel_id = key`